# How to use javac -d code form in windows?

Tags: java, command

I want to compile a file inside a folder with respect to the current path I have opened the command prompt. But I used it like this

```
 javac -d A.java
```

But this was a possible effort in ubuntu. But it is not working in windows. Can anybody help to make this work in windows7..

Comment: *"is not working"* is not a useful problem description. What exactly happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the path, where you want to store your classes with package structure. May be a `.` for current working directory. Try like this:

```
javac -d . A.java
```